# Did Objective-C get more liberal? Dot notation for non properties

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I've noticed that I can use dot notation in iOS 5 beta/XCode 4.2 beta, even for methods that are not properties, like `Singleton.instance` when the method signature is merely `+ (Singleton*) instance`. If I recall correctly, I couldn't do this in XCode 4.1.

1. Has this really changed, or have I gone mad?
2. If it has changed, where's the change documented?

Comment: Keep in mind Xcode 4.2 is still in private developer beta so it's understandable that some new features are undocumented. And even when it goes public, they might consider this too insignificant to mention in release notes as the feature was there for a long time (since Objective-C 2.0 I think), it was just not handled by auto-complete as Kevin explained.

Comment: This appears similar to a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100495/nsarray-and-other-cocoa-types-property-values) I asked a while back. :-)

Comment: @Sedate Alien, I think it's a different question, though yours is good too. Do you think it's a dupe?

Comment: @fichek, good point. On the other hand, I only know that because I have Kevin's answer :) I really thought that before it gave me a compiler warning, but I'm not curious enough to roll my machine back to 4.1.

Comment: @fichek now that 4.2 has been released out of beta, is it still understandable that some new features are undocumented? Or now are they documented, which would be cool. Apparently "release notes" is not the right search term: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing has changed except Xcode's code completion. The compiler always allowed you to use dot-notation for methods, only Xcode wouldn't offer methods as code completion suggestions for dot notation. Xcode 4.2 seems to have changed that behavior.